# Differentiate between 2 sets of MKAnnotations on the same mapview Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have listed the relevant code below.
Essentially, I have 2 annotations I am trying to customise;

annotation1 I want to use an image to represent locations received from a URL.
annotation2 is to be represented by simple pins as they will be for locations searched in-app by the user, I also need to remove annotation2 when a user presses cancel without affecting annotation1

Essentially, I have tried using IF statements but my app keeps crashing otherwise they are all represented by the image of annotation1 and are all removed when I try to remove just annotation2

*Below are the code representing annotations in ViewController.m*

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize searchBar;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

 }

- (void) dismissKeyboard
{
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [_mapView removeAnnotations:_mapView.annotations];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *identifier;
    {
        if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) return nil;

        MKAnnotationView *annotationView;
        if (annotationView == nil) {
             annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            annotationView.enabled = YES;
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
            annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bullet_red.png"];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        return annotationView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

*Below is the code also in ViewController.m that is the source for both annotation1 and annotation2, it might not be relevant, but just in case*

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:self.searchBar.text completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D newLocation = [placemark.location coordinate];
        region.center = [(CLCircularRegion *)placemark.region center];

        MKPointAnnotation *mapAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        [mapAnnotation setCoordinate:newLocation];
        [mapAnnotation setTitle:self.searchBar.text];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:mapAnnotation];

        MKMapRect mr = [self.mapView visibleMapRect];
        MKMapPoint pt = MKMapPointForCoordinate([mapAnnotation coordinate]);
        mr.origin.x = pt.x - mr.size.width * 0.5;
        mr.origin.y = pt.y - mr.size.height *0.25;
        [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:mr animated:YES];
    }];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSMutableArray *_locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];

        MKPointAnnotation* marker = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        coordinate.latitude = [jsonElement [@"Latitude"] doubleValue];
        coordinate.longitude = [jsonElement [@"Longitude"] doubleValue];
        marker.coordinate = coordinate;
        [_locations addObject:marker];
    }

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:_locations];
}
```

Comment: Instead of using the generic MKPointAnnotation which makes it difficult to tell annotations apart, use two different custom annotation classes or one custom annotation class with an additional property specifying its "type".

Comment: By the way, in viewForAnnotation, between the declaration of `annotationView` and checking if it's `nil`, you probably want to call `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` otherwise there's a risk with using an uninitialized local variable.